# .htaccess : using http_referer accessing a folder just if the user is logged in (in another part of the server)

Tags: .htaccess, http-referer

i'm trying to put online a web application.

I'd like users to get to this application (which requires authentication) just after having done another authentication on a wordpress site.

to explain it better : after gaining access to a member only area of a wordpres site, you can access to a private page which is linking to the final web application. The folder of the final web application should be accessed only from user following that link.

i suppose the logic is to deny all except those who pass the http_referer of the private page..

but i'm blocked here (and don't know if it's useful as a security policy).

Comment: First, referrer header is **AN OPTIONAL HEADER** and users can disable it, if you generate some hash for every logged in user and check it on second server, it would be better

Answer (score 2):

You can try.

`Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?yoursite.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?anyothersiteyouwanttoallowaccess.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^/?path/you-want-restricted.html http://www.whereyouwantthemredirected.com [NC,R,L]`